# How to redirect to a controller when a specific url is hit in java spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a URL say:**[www.xyz.com/abc](http://www.xyz.com/abc)** and I want to redirect to a controller say:**abcController.form**. How can I implement this?

Actually I tried URLrewrite as below:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/abc$</from>
    <to last="true" type="redirect">/abccontroller.form</to>
</rule>
```

but its showing 404 URL not found in server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward) who gives very good explanations. TL;DR:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RedirectController {
    
    @GetMapping("/abc")
    public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingRedirectPrefix(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("attribute", "redirectWithRedirectPrefix");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedUrl", model);
    }
}
```

It's about the `redirect:` prefix. This will do a redirect in your Controller.